# Not able to append a paragraph to the image element

Tags: javascript, html

I made this favImages array and added some image objects to it. Then I am trying to append a paragraph element(removeButton) to each of them which will be triggered by clicking the images.

```js
var favImages = new Object();
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  favImages[i] = document.getElementById("fav" + (i + 1));
}

var removeButton = document.createElement("p");
removeButton.id = "removebutton";
removeButton.innerHTML = "Remove Image";

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var newImage = document.getElementById(favImages[i].id);
  newImage.addEventListener("click", function() {
    newImage.appendChild(removeButton)
  }, false);
}
```

Comment: A single element can only be in the DOM once. You have to make separate elements for each image.

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please update with relevant HTML

Comment: how can i use a loop to do that ?

Comment: Don't use a loop. Use an event listener on the container and test what was clicked using event.target. You cannot add a child to an image

Comment: If `newImage` really is an `img` element, you can't append elements to it. [`img`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#technical_summary) is an empty element, it can't have any content.

Comment: Got it, so you cannot append an element to the image .. thank you so much !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a loop. Use an event listener on the container and test what was clicked using event.target. You cannot add a child to an image

You COULD use a div, put the image as a background and the span to click as content

Anyway here are some examples

```js
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("remove")) tgt.closest("div").remove()
})
```

```css
#container div {
  width: 200px
}

.remove {
  float: right
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>
    <span class="remove">X</span>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/000888?text=image1" />

  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="remove">X</span>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF00FF/000888?text=image2" />

  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="remove">X</span>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/000888?text=image3" />

  </div>
</div>
```

From an array:

```js
const images = [
  "https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/000888?text=image1",
  "https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF00FF/000888?text=image2",
  "https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/000888?text=image3"
];

const container = document.getElementById("container");
container.innerHTML = images.map(img => `<div><span class="remove">X</span>
    <img src="${img}" /></div>`).join("");


container.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("remove")) tgt.closest("div").remove()
})
```

```css
#container div {
  width: 200px
}

.remove {
  float: right
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

</div>
```